# How do I plot a vector data in a spatial visualization, using GGMAP?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geolocation, spatial, ggmap

I'm having some trouble trying to make a spatial visualisation of my data using the package `ggmap`.

> **I already have:**

1. `ggmap` package
2. Lat_lon of my business
3. Lat_lon of my 250 customers

I wanna plot my business in green and my customers in red, over a map of my city.

> **Here's my code atm:**

Comment: maybe you have 245 rows of invalid LAT and LON for Ribeirao Preto

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of data/code. Copy-paste them.

Comment: Please learn how to produce a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)

Comment: @pcantalupo, I already tried to plot them using google maps... and it worked.

Comment: @Heroka, thanks.. already changed that!

Comment: @Jaap, already bookmarked that page. thanks a lot!

Comment: Your customer lat/lon values are pretty far away from *Ribeirao Preto*. Try another zoomlevel (e.g. 8) will help.

Comment: @Jaap, I used zoom = 5 and the error continues... only my business is displayed in the map.

it looks like it's something wrong in my `dados_empr`... as it plots only 2 of my 245 values.. is there any way to upload my .csv here?

Comment: With `dput(dados_empr)` you wil get output that starts with `structure(...`. You can paste that output in the question.

Comment: I think you need `zoom=4`

Comment: @Jaap, well... it seems that my geocode() haven't worked properly.... I think I should refine my adresses and get the coordinates again. / 

Using zoom = 2 I saw that some of my customers are plotted in wrong cities... but at least I can see them in my map... /

I'll improve my data and try again. /

Thanks for your efforts in helping me. You should create an answer, so I can accept your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have some customers far far away from your business. You will therefore have to use an appropriate zoom-level; in your case `zoom=3` will include most datapoints. With:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)

rp <- get_map(location = 'Ribeirao Preto', zoom = 3, maptype = 'satellite', color = "bw")

ggmap(rp) +
  geom_point(data = dados_empr, aes(x = lon, y = lat), color = 'red', size = 2, shape=19, alpha=0.5) +
  geom_point(data = dados_grnd,  aes(x = lon, y = lat), color = 'green', size = 3, shape=19)
```

I get:

[image]